# Error executing API while fetching folder list of blob

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

I am creating logicapp to trigger app when there is a update or modification in blob and copy this to sharepoint. I am getting below error while setting connection to blob

Error executing the api '/v2/datasets/sae1stlrsmpgdevshdatlake/rootfoldersV2'.

Any imputs on how to fix the issue

I have tried updating the CORS setting and all, not sure that is the right resolution

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from my end, I got the expected results as per your requirement without any errors using the below flow. I have used Azure functions in order to get the headers for the list blob API.

[image]

Sample code in my function app

```
import datetime
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64
import azure.functions as func
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:

    STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME = '<STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME>'
    STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY = "<STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY>"
    CONTAINER_NAME = '<CONTAINER_NAME>'
    REQUEST_VERSION = '2020-04-08'
    REQUEST_DATE = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT')
    CANONICALIZED_HEADERS = f'x-ms-date:{REQUEST_DATE}\nx-ms-version:{REQUEST_VERSION}\n'
    CANONICALIZED_RESOURCE = f'/{STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME}/{CONTAINER_NAME}\ncomp:list\nrestype:container'

    VERB = 'GET'
    Content_Encoding = ''
    Content_Language = ''
    Content_Length = ''
    Content_MD5 = ''
    Content_Type = ''
    Date = ''
    If_Modified_Since = ''
    If_Match = ''
    If_None_Match = ''
    If_Unmodified_Since = ''
    Range = ''
    CanonicalizedHeaders = CANONICALIZED_HEADERS
    CanonicalizedResource = CANONICALIZED_RESOURCE

    STRING_TO_SIGN = (VERB + '\n' + Content_Encoding + '\n' + Content_Language + '\n' +
                Content_Length + '\n' + Content_MD5 + '\n' + Content_Type + '\n' +
                Date + '\n' + If_Modified_Since + '\n' + If_Match + '\n' +
                If_None_Match + '\n' + If_Unmodified_Since + '\n' + Range + '\n' +
                CanonicalizedHeaders + CanonicalizedResource)

    signature = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(base64.b64decode(STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY), msg=STRING_TO_SIGN.encode('utf-8'), digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()).decode()
    auth_header = f'SharedKey {STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME}:{signature}'

    request_url = f'https://{STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME}.blob.core.windows.net/{CONTAINER_NAME}?restype=container&comp=list'


    request_headers = {
    'x-ms-date': REQUEST_DATE,
    'x-ms-version': REQUEST_VERSION,
    'Authorization': auth_header
    }

    response = requests.get(request_url, headers=request_headers).text
    root = ET.fromstring(response)
    
    BlobNames=[]
    for i in range(len(root[0])):
        x = root[0][i][0].text
        if(x.startswith('sample/')):
            BlobNames.append(x)


    return func.HttpResponse(str(BlobNames))
```

##### Blobs in my Storage account

[image]

##### Results:

[image]